# Global array not updating after .push inside function

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, global

Hey guys anyone who can help my out?
Basically I want to make a breaking news footer that loops through the newsWire array and updates the text automatically. Problem is when I run my console.log(newsWire.length) outside the loadNewswire function it returns a 0, while the console.log inside returns 40 as it should?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/u8y8zh72/3/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <style>
        footer {
            height: 75px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden"></ul>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container" id="newswiretxt">
        <span></span>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newsWire = [];
    function loadNewswire() {
        $.getJSON('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all.json',
        {'api-key': 'XXXXXXXXX'},
        function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            var newsWireTemp = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                var breakingNews = data.results[i];
                var breakingTitle = breakingNews.title;
                var breakingAbstract = breakingNews.abstract;
                newsWireTemp.push(breakingTitle);
                newsWireTemp.push(breakingAbstract);
            }
            newsWire = newsWireTemp;
            console.log(newsWire.length);
        });
    }
    loadNewswire();
    console.log(newsWire.length);


    $(document).ready(function() {
    var items = newsWire;
    $text = $('#newswiretxt span'),
    delay = 10; //seconds
    function loop (delay) {
        $.each(items, function (i, elm){
            $text.delay(delay*1E3).fadeOut();
            $text.queue(function(){
                $text.html(items[i]);
                $text.dequeue();
            });
            $text.fadeIn();
            $text.queue(function(){
                if (i == items.length -1) {
                    loop(delay);   
                }
            $text.dequeue();
            });
        });
    }
    loop(delay);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `loadNewswire()` makes an asynchronous call. That means that `console.log(newsWire.length);` runs before the callback (`newsWire = newsWireTemp;`). You can tell that because you `console.log(newsWire.length)` is being output after `console.log(newsWire.length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing is this:

```
...
loadNewswire();
console.log(newsWire.length);
...
```

When you call `loadNewsWire`, you're starting an asynchronous JSON request. However, the script execution won't wait for that function to complete, so it immediately runs the following `console.log` statement. At that point, the JSON request hasn't completed, so the `newsWire` array is still empty - which is why `console.log(newsWire.length)` returns 0 there.

Inside your `loadNewsWire` function, you have a callback function that gets executed when the JSON request has returned your data. At this point you're populating the array, and `console.log(newsWire.length)` gives you the expected count.

---

**Update in response to comment:**

> Is there anyway to make the rest of my code wait for the function to
>   execute?

Yes! `$.getJSON` is a convenience wrapper for `$.ajax`, which returns a `jqXHR` object (full juicy details in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)). You can add additional callbacks to that object, which is what you're actually doing inline in your call to `$.getJSON`. The following:

```
$.getJSON('http://...', { 'api-key': '...' },
    function (data) {
        // stuff
    });
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$.getJSON('http://...', { 'api-key': '...' })
    .done(function (data) {
        // stuff
    });
```

So, if you modify your `loadNewswire` to return the object returned from `$.getJSON`, you can attach a callback to it that will wait for the async operation to complete, and place the rest of your code inside that. If you change your code to this:

```
function loadNewswire() {
    return $.getJSON(
        ...
    );
};
```

You can then wrap the code you want to wait using one of the `done`, `fail` or `always` callbacks.

Your calling code would then look like this:

```
loadNewswire().done(function () {
    console.log(newsWire.length);
    // and any other code you want to hold until the async operation is complete
});
```

I'd suggest reading through the [previously mentioned documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) - it's a bit heavy, but it gives a good overview of how to work with async requests using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, that was my thought as well, since I could see the timing in my console of when the numbers appeared. Is there anyway to make the rest of my code wait for the function to execute?

Comment: @JeppeGelardiMadsen Updated answer for your comment.